# Python pulp optimizer with min absolute value

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, pulp

I'm using pulp (https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/) for optimization purposes and get issue. I need to use constraint like `abs(x) > MIN` and I found solution here http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/absolute.htm, I just create two constraints:

```
x + M * B >= MIN
-x + M * (1 - B) >= MIN
```

Where B is 0 or 1 and M big enough value. The problem is that when I use M ~ 10000 everything works great, but when I use INT_MAX_VALUE or ~ 10000000000 it doesn't work.
Have anyone get issues like this?

Comment: `B` is a boolean variable, why would you use a value such as `10000` or `100000000000`?

Comment: `M` should be chosen as small as possible (otherwise you get into serious numerical trouble as you noticed). In your case you could consider `M` as a  bound on `x`, i.e. |x| <= M. In practical cases we often know a good bound on |x|.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you go better with COIN-CBC. I saw your numerical Issues in another post and it seems, it just comes from some VUB constraints.

First the LP solver (CLP) behind CBC is more elaborate  then GLPK and second  you can use **SOS constraints**, which model these VUB constraints, which u wanna use for your abs-Function mucht better (without any numerical hazards, it just branches them out). And overall the performance is usually better.
Feel free to follow up my answer and comment the question.